# Return field from List of string[] in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of strings[].

I want to use Linq to return one field of the string[] from the List<>.

Currently I am doing this:

```
string[] Cashrow = ParsedSales.First(x=>x.Contains("CALC CASH"));
double Cash= Convert.ToDouble(Cashrow[1]);
```

which works just fine. My question is if it is possible to write this in a single statement?

I would like a LINQ query that returns the individual field rather than the row.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that, which is why I deleted the comment :)

Comment: @Tim: please read the question more carefully. It's obvious that ParsedSales ist a List of string[].

Comment: @oliver - Read my most recent comment :)

Comment: You could literally inline the variable `double Cash = Convert.ToDouble(ParsedSales.First(x=>x.Contains("CALC CASH"))[1]);`  But making code one line shouldn't be your goal.  It should be to make it correct and readable.

Comment: That did it! I just needed the [1] (index of the returned array, I assume).  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, instead of getting the first, compose the query with a `Where` and a `Select`:

```
double cash = ParsedSales
    .Where(x => x.Contains("CALC CASH"));
    .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x[1]))
    .First();
```